# VBA Regex - match entire string unless repeating pattern

Tags: regex, vba

I am vexed - and I suspect there is an easy solution to this but after a fair amount of research, I'm reaching out to the community.

I'm using the regex method in vba to try to split strings.  What I want to occur is that the entire string will match the pattern unless there is another name in the string.  The name can be described by:

```
"\s?[a-zA-Z-]*,\s[a-zA-Z]*:\s.*"
```

I would expect that the method would return everything after the name is matched - until another name is matched.  This would be the desired outcome.

The strings I'm applying that pattern to are:

Meck, Mary: Fri 6/14/2019 5:00 PM -- 10:00 PM CLERKPETRO Flinstone, Fred: Fri 6/14/2019 10:00 AM -- 4:00 PM CLERKPETRO Powers, Kenny: Fri 6/14/2019 10:00 PM -- 11:00 PM

Rhodes, Randy: Sat 6/15/2019 10:15 AM -- 11:30 AM SERVCNTR Sat 6/15/2019 11:30 AM -- 12:45 PM CLICK AND PICK Sat 6/15/2019 12:45 PM -- 2:15 PM SERVCNTR

When I apply the pattern to either string, the entire string is returned.  This is not optimal because I'm trying to split on names using matches(0), matches(1), etc..  so the first string should match on:

1. Meck, Mary: Fri 6/14/2019 5:00 PM -- 10:00 PM CLERKPETRO
2. Flinstone, Fred: Fri 6/14/2019 10:00 AM -- 4:00 PM CLERKPETRO
3. Powers, Kenny: Fri 6/14/2019 10:00 PM -- 11:00 PM

yet the second string should match on the entire string (as it currently does) because there is not a second name in that string.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it

`\b[a-zA-Z-]+,\s?[a-zA-Z]+:.*?(?=\b[a-zA-Z-]+,\s?[a-zA-Z]+:|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/ccj6ea/1

Expanded

```
 \b 
 [a-zA-Z-]+ 
 , 
 \s? 
 [a-zA-Z]+ 
 : 
 .*? 
 (?=
      \b 
      [a-zA-Z-]+ 
      , 
      \s? 
      [a-zA-Z]+ 
      : 
   |  
      $ 
 )
```

Comment: So at the end of that expression where it says.*?(?=\b[a-zA-Z-]+,\s?[a-zA-Z]+:|$) are you saying match everything unless ? where ? = that expression you defined between \b and |$?  If so, what does the \b do?  Is that some kind of literal operator?  Also what does the |$ do?  I've used the pipe "|" before to represent the or operator in patterns but I am unclear on what "or $" - |$ would do.  Thanks again.

Comment: Matches everything up to, but not including `(?=\b[a-zA-Z-]+,\s?[a-zA-Z]+:|$)` . This is an assertion that encapsulates the constructs of the first part of the match, which is being used to find the _start_ of the next match. The alternation `|$` is just incase there is no next match, it matches the end of the string. Also, `\b` is called a word boundary, which is an assertion that looks behind then ahead and matches the position between 2 characters where one is a non-word, the other is a word.

Answer (score 0):

#### RegEx 1

I'm guessing that we wish to capture three parts of the strings listed in the question, which if that might be the case, we would be starting by slightly modifying the original expression:

```
(?:\s+)?([a-zA-Z-]+),?(?:\s+)?([a-zA-Z]+):(.+?[A-Z]{3,}).*
```

where our desired outputs are in these three groups:

```
([a-zA-Z-]+)
([a-zA-Z]+)
(.+?[A-Z]{3,})
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lAhOML/1/)

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### RegEx 2

If we wish to split them on names, we would simplify our expression to:

```
(?:\s+)?([A-Z][a-zA-Z-]+),?(?:\s+)?([A-Z][a-zA-Z]+):
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/pNa5I3/1/)

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to capture the date and 2+ time strings in each matched string.  The purpose is to use logic to test if there are more than 2 time strings (should always occur in multiples of 2 because start1, end1, start2, end2, start3, end3...) if the end1 is right before start2 and if end 2 is right before start 3.  Trying to figure out if the times are adjacent to understand if that's one shift with multiple series' of times next to eachother or if it's multiple shifts over multiple times/days.